# Why does Microsoft visual studio 2019 close automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 enterprise and it gives me an error every time I open it.
I didn't know what the problem was, so I left it until now the program sometimes closes automatically, this is the program log file, please tell me what is the problem and how can I fix this? thanks!

```
=====================
2/18/2021 12:05:22 PM
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================
```

Comment: Visual Studio closes (and restarts) automatically if it crashes. You seem to be having some broken project settings. Try a clean build

Comment: It's not just about one project. I tried C# console, C++ console, Xamarin and C# windows form and it still shows this error! I don't know what to do

Comment: When I saw something similar last time (not sure it was really the same, but it looked a bit like it) a repair installation fixed it. Start the Visual Studio Installer and select "Repair" from the "More" dropdown.

Comment: Are you running 16.8.5? I work on the team that owns the code at the top of this stack trace. If upgrading/repairing VS doesn't help, please file an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to start VS as administrator? I've resolved many many problems by doing that :)

Comment: PMF: Visual studio installer doesn't detect installed packages I think I have to reinstall it completly

Comment: Guillermo Gerard: Run as administrator doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try start it in safe mode, sometimes it fixes things and is able to lauch in normal afterwards:

Edit the shortcut you might have (depending your your version, community, professional or enterprise, use appropriate subfolder..):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /safemode
```

Comment: There isn't community folder in 2019, there's just one folder was named enterprise

Comment: Depending your your version, community, professional or enterprise, use appropriate subfolder..

Answer (score 0):

Try runing the "Visual Studio Installer" app on your PC and choosing the "Repair" option.

Comment: It was 2 years ago, I don't even have windows anymore